How to remove token from localstorage and render logout page in Next JS?
I have created a next js web app and I want to render logout page if token gets expired and simultaneously remove expired token from localstorage. How to make sure this functionality runs irrespective of page user loads in in the app?
Used this on homepage but this doesn't work on other pages, while I want this to run irrespective of page user is on.
useEffect(()=>{
    if (!token)
    localStorage.removeItem('key');
    },[])


Do you set this in header or where do you set this currently?
I think just don't set this in the homepage or in a page.tsx but in layout.tsx or in header.tsx that we use in all pages
examples on how to do it in layout
"use client"

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) {
      // Perform logout actions and redirect to the logout page
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      router.push('/logout');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your layout components */}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;


is this a question or an answere? format this to an valid possible answere please or remove it and add a comment to the question.

i have updated my answer for what i mean in doing it in layout

Thanks for the solution. In my application there are many components which are common and used on every page so have fixed this out by defining over there. @Zulzidan.com
